# Can i upgrade my Lenovo v110 15iap cpu proccessor

Tags: laptop, cpu, upgrade

I have a lenovo v110 15iap and the cpu is soldered in the motherboard is there any way I can upgrade it?

Comment: The only way to upgrade it is to buy a new laptop or [find a complete motherboard](https://www.google.com/search?&q=lenovo+v110+motherboard) dismantle the entire laptop and replace what you currently have. The CPU itself is not replaceable and any place that would replace it will charge you far more than the laptop is worth.

Answer (score 0):

No, CPUs that are soldered on can't be upgraded.